# Why is the .replace() method not working?

Tags: python, string

Below is a simple piece of code that accepts 2 strings and removes all characters from the 2nd string which are present in the 1st string:

```
s1 = 'aeiou'
s2 = 'this is python program'

checkFor = []
for i in s1:
  checkFor.append(i)

for i in s2:
  if i in checkFor:
    print(i)
    s2.replace(i, '')

print(s2)
```

This is the output I'm getting:

```
i
i
o
o
a
this is python program
```

The if block is getting executed but why is the .replace() method not working? or is there a better way of deleting a character from a string?

Comment: `.replace()` *is* working.  You're just not doing anything with the new string that it produces.

Comment: in addition to answers below, how about using list comprehensions instead? `''.join([i for i in s2 if i not in s1])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save `s2.replace()` somewhere and print it.

```
for i in s2:
  if i in checkFor:
    print(i)
    s2 = s2.replace(i, '')

print(s2)
```

Comment: ... This way you would be overwriting the previous value of `s3` each turn and going back to the original `s2`.

Comment: I see. I updated it.

Comment: youre still printing `s3`, not `s2`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not assigning the value of replace:

```
s2 = s2.replace(i, '')
```